# Applying for similar jobs through same recruiter

Tags: software-industry, recruitment, new-job, first-job

I have recently completed my masters and also worked on one SharePoint project.

I have applied to 7-8 jobs with similar roles through the online job portals advertised by the same recruiter agency. It seems to be a big recruitment agency. One of the recruiters contacted me for Company A and performed a small interview via the phone. A second recruiter from the same recruitment agency contacted me about a job with Company B.

My questions are:

- Does it make a bad impression to apply for different companies from the same recruitment agency?
- Should I tell each recruiter that I have been contacted by their colleague and I am engaging with them as well about other jobs?
- Can I tell different salary expectations to different recruiters for similar job roles?
- Lastly, Do two recruiter talk about their clients information such as who is applying for what?

I know these are different questions but all are under the same context.

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with having different salary expectations for similar jobs.  You might choose to work for Company A for slightly less money because Company B is further away from where you live, for example; or maybe Company A has a better pension scheme, or has flexi-time.  These things are benefits that to you may have an equivalent financial value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had some experiences with recruiters, so:

> Does it make a bad impression to apply for different companies from
>   the same recruitment agency?

NO. The job of a recruiter is to find the best position for someone that is looking for a job, so if you think that you are suitable for more that one position is your right try to find the best one.

> Should I tell each recruiter that I have been contacted by their
>   colleague and I am engaging with them as well about other jobs?

Depends. If they are from the same recruiting agency, no, they should know.
If they are from different agency the etiquette says that you have to inform only if they are trying to submit your application to the same company.
Example:

Recruiter A: want to submit your application to company XYZ? Ok.

Recruiter B: want to submit your application to company XYZ? No, someone else already applied for me there.

> Can I tell different salary expectations to different recruiters for
>   similar job roles?

Yes, depends on how you feel for the position, but I recommend to ask for a range of salary or around a salary.
example: From 30k to 32k OR around 30k

> Lastly, Do two recruiters talk about their clients' information, such as
>   who is applying for what?

Yes, usually they do if they are from the same agency.

Answer (score 1):

The recruiter's job is to recruit you, i.e - connect you to a job.

So when you ask:

> Does two recruiter talk about their clients information such as who is
>   applying for what?

It really doesn't matter to them, and they know that you have the right to apply anywhere, multiple places.

Different salaries? Of course that is fine as well. It really depends on your own situation. It is very understandable to tailor your salary to a specific geography/company/job-potential/etc.

> Should I tell each recruiter that I have contacted by their colleague
>   and I am engaging with them as well about other the job role

Why would you need to do this ?  As long as you are sincere about the opportunities you are looking into , all is well.

To summarize, you are doing fine. carry on !

Answer (score 1):

As Adel said recruiters job is to get you the best job that fits with your potential.
So to do this they will do anything possible to have their name high in the recruitment business.So it'll be wasting your time and money if you apply through single recruiter for one company and wasting recruiters reputation too as they won't have much probability of getting you the job.

Coming to your second question.
It is a whole team looking forward to have you recruited so different people from their team  May contact you .

Third one is common doing as salary expectation changes with demography and position you are applying for.

For your last question
Recruiters have hundreds to thousands of applicant at a time,So they are not that a much bothered about who is applying for what.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I tell each recruiter that I have been contacted by their
>   colleague and I am engaging with them as well about other jobs?

Generally, the more upfront, honest and transparent you seem, the better. I always notify the recruiters whenever a situation could arise that potentially could reflect badly on me if/when they discover they have been wasting their time.

On the other hand, by notifying them you risk that they concentrate on the job that makes **more financial sense for them** and not necessarily you.

Answer (score 1):

I have applied to multiple jobs with the same recruiter. They only get paid when they find you a job, so they do not care which one it is. Remember that they have nothing at all to do with the companies you apply for and are competing against other agencies.

I would tell them if a colleague has already contacted you though, as they may want to have that one person be in charge of all your applications and they can share information.